# Build custom RESTful API or use apify?

Tags: php, api, rest, laravel

I just was assigned the task to implement an API service for a developed web app, and I was advised to check out [apify](http://apifydoc.com/) before starting to write code to build a custom api.

The app is built on Laravel, so, what do you advice? Should I go for apify? Will I save that much time and work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you implementing a RESTful API? If you are using Laravel,perhaps this bundle is what you need - http://bundles.laravel.com/bundle/rest_service_api

Also, take a look here - http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#restful-controllers